# Kafka-node - BrokerNotAvailableError

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a kafka-node `("kafka-node": "^2.6.1",)` client, which successfully produces messages when i run node app in localhost and connect with `remote_address:2181`. But the same code produces below error when deploy to a test server.

```
BrokerNotAvailableError: Broker not available
0|www      |     at new BrokerNotAvailableError (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/errors/BrokerNotAvailableError.js:11:9)
0|www      |     at Client.loadMetadataForTopics (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:371:15)
0|www      |     at Client.send (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:542:10)
0|www      |     at /var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:240:10
0|www      |     at /var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
0|www      |     at iteratorCallback (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)
0|www      |     at /var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
0|www      |     at buildRequest (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:256:24)
0|www      |     at /var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3110:16
0|www      |     at eachOfArrayLike (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1069:9)
0|www      |     at eachOf (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1117:5)
0|www      |     at Object.eachLimit (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3172:5)
0|www      |     at Client.sendProduceRequest (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:238:9)
0|www      |     at HighLevelProducer.BaseProducer.send (/var/www/backend/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/baseProducer.js:120:10)
0|www      |     at /var/www/backend/clients/3rdparty/kafka.js:104:16
```

Possible causes could be the remoteServer blocks incoming requests at port 2181, but i am able to telnet at `remote_address:2181`. Here is my code:

```
const clientConfig = {
connectionString: process.env.KAFKA_HOST,
clientId: process.env.KAFKA_CLIENTID || 'nodejs-kafka-client'
}
client = new kafka.Client(clientConfig.connectionString, 
clientConfig.clientId)

producer = new kafka.HighLevelProducer(client, {})
bindListeners()
```

I read about a [similar issue](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/685) issue on kafka-node repo. The guy who raised the issue, seemed to resolve it using some zookeeper config. I use the default config of zookeeper. I am not sure if that's one of the reason, as i am able to connect with my localhost.

Comment: Instead of debugging connectivity with `telnet`, you should use the kafka bin utilities to test if you're able to produce (with `kafka-console-producer.sh`) and consume (`kafka-console-consumer.sh `) topics offsets with the same broker's host and port that you use in your node app.

Comment: Those connect directly with kafka broker at :9092 port, kafka-node connects via zookeeper at :2181. I believe something is up with zookeeper.

Comment: Maybe that's your problem. I don't use often node.js but with recent versions of kafka it's recommended to use the kafka broker/cluster host and port directly (either for consumers or producers).

Comment: Moreover your error message mentioned a "broker not available" not a "zookeeper" so try to use the broker port instead.

Comment: As mentioned above in question. Everything works when client connects from local nodejs server to remote zookeeper, but not from a remote node-server.

Comment: Then debug the remote connection with the kafka utility scripts (you can install those scripts in your node server to debug the connectivity). If it works try to use exactly the same configuration (hostname and port). Also check the advertised hostname in your kafka configuration, you might need to use the same. And again: you shouldn't use the zookeeper port in your configuration, it's a deprecated way.

Comment: Agreed, its a deprecated way. I read more about it. Switched directly to kafka-broker. Check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added kafka IP in /etc/hosts

After that I was able to solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

For all of you guys, trying out kafka-node.

Try using kafka.KafkaClient() instead of kafka.client(). It uses, Kafka-broker directly, instead of connecting via zookeeper.

Although, i am sure zookeeper configuration can also be updated to support kafka.client() way. But i am not sure, what is the actual configuration.

Comment: did you test it with aws ? please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650664/how-to-connect-aws-bitnami-certified-kafka-ami-with-elastic-beanstalk-nodejs-env/56670465?noredirect=1#comment100074818_56670465